# JaCoCo Gradle Kotlin DSL exclude file from violation rules

Tags: gradle, jacoco, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to set my project up to run JaCoCo and to fail the build if it has less that 80% test coverage.  The caveat is that I want to exclude a particular file and I can't seem to make that work.  I have scoured the web and read oodles of Stack Overflow answers, blog posts, and the documentation for the plugin, but I cannot make anything work.  It always still includes the file that I am trying to exclude.

I started with:

```
tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = "0.8".toBigDecimal()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which obviously will include everything and it does. I have tried the following variations based on what I have read, but none of them have worked:

```
tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            classDirectories.setFrom(sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree.matching {
                exclude("path.to.my.class.HelloWorld")
            })
            limit {
                minimum = "0.8".toBigDecimal()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    classDirectories.setFrom(
            sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree.matching {
                exclude("path.to.my.class.HelloWorld")
            }
    )
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = "0.8".toBigDecimal()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = "0.8".toBigDecimal()
            }
        }
    }
}
tasks {
    getByName<JacocoReport>("jacocoTestReport") {
        afterEvaluate {
            classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.map {
                fileTree(it) {
                    exclude("path.to.my.class.HelloWorld")
                }
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

```
tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = "0.8".toBigDecimal()
            }
        }
    }
}
tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
    classDirectories.setFrom(
        sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree.matching {
            exclude("path.to.my.class.HelloWorld")
        }
    )
}
```

The output of all of these is exactly the same:

```
Execution failed for task ':jacocoTestCoverageVerification'.
> Rule violated for bundle OneUIBackend: instructions covered ratio is 0.6, but expected minimum is 0.8
```

Does anyone have any insight in to how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that I was declaring the excluded file as a classpath rather than a filepath.  The final solution is:

```
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn(tasks.test)
    finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification)
    classDirectories.setFrom(
            sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree.matching {
                exclude("path/to/my/file/HelloWorld*")
            }
    )
}
tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            classDirectories.setFrom(sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree.matching {
                exclude("path/to/my/file/HelloWorld*")
            })
            limit {
                minimum = "0.8".toBigDecimal()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

An addition to the accepted solution (that also worked for me; for kotlin project using kotlin gradle dsl; gradle 7.2; jacoco plugin 0.8.7)

- In case you are trying to figure out how to exclude classes from coverage report using `afterEvaluate {...}` the following worked for me:

  ```
  tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
      afterEvaluate {
          classDirectories.setFrom(classDirectories.files.map {
              fileTree(it).matching {
                  exclude("com/**")
              }
          })
      }
  }
  ```

  Putting the `afterEvaluate` block inside `tasks.jacocoTestReport {...}` result in an error:

  > Project#afterEvaluate(Action) on root project 'demo' cannot be executed in the current context
- You can reuse `classDirectories` from `jacocoTestReport` task in `jacocoTestCoverageVerification`:

  ```
  tasks.jacocoTestReport {
      dependsOn(tasks.test)
      finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification)

      classDirectories.setFrom(classDirectories.files.map {
          fileTree(it).matching {
              exclude("com/**")
          }
      })
  }

  tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
      violationRules {
          rule {
              classDirectories.setFrom(tasks.jacocoTestReport.get().classDirectories)
              limit {
                  minimum = "0.78".toBigDecimal()
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to exclude a bit clearer:

```kotlin
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    classDirectories.setFrom(
        files(classDirectories.files.map {
            fileTree(it) {
                exclude(
                    "com/example/integration/**",
                    "com/example/application/*Ext*"
                )
            }
        })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for Gradle 7.6.1 (use `setExcludes` instead of `exclude`)

```
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        html.required.set(true)
        xml.required.set(true)
    }
    classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.map {
        fileTree(it) {
            setExcludes(listOf(
                    "**/first/path/to/skip/*.class",
                    "**/second/path/to/skip/*.class"
            ))
        }
    }))
}
```